# Invalid string value: '\ xD0...." for the column .... ". utf8 charset try used

Tags: java, mysql, spring, utf-8

In the spring project, I try to introduce *Cyrillic* characters into the database. But the database does not encode it.

I used the extended JpaRepository interface, method save (T t), and everything works correctly when I send English text;

when the program tries to save the entity with the Cyrillic, I get the exception "Invalid string value: '\ xD0 \ xA5 \ xD0 \ xB0 \ xD0 \ xB1 ..." for the column .... "

So encoding does not work.

### My database character variables:

[image]

### application.properties:

```
launchMode=cli

#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySecondBD?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

## Question:

## Where more I need set charset encoding params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, I do next steps and all runs:

- edit application.properties, how me advised

  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySecondBD?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
- changed own my table encode property(not only database):

  ALTER TABLE page CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
  ALTER TABLE page CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
- and I changed variable column into text:

  alter TABLE page MODIFY content TEXT(21844);

PS variables of the database:

```
| Variable_name            | Value                      |

| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit properties :

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySecondBD?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Check your variables :

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
```

Edit my.cnf :

```
vi /etc/my.cnf

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Finally, you recheck your MySQL variables and confirm your query result.

Answer (score 1):

Hex `D0A5D0B0D0B1` is the UTF-8 encoding for Cyrillic `Хаб`.  So, using MySQL's utf8 (or utf8mb4) should work.

When you said `'\ xD0 \ xA5 \ xD0 \ xB0 \ xD0 \ xB1 ..."`, you had extra spaces; were they in the output you saw?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE page`.

Somehow, you need to say that the *client* encoding is utf8.  One way (in spring) is to put this in the `application.yml`:

```
 datasource:
     connectionInitSql: "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Used this query , it works for me...
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN  `column_name` varchar(255)
     CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;